# How to allow NetBeans in the iptables firewall for project-type plugins?

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

So intend to do web development with NetBeans. However the HTML/JavaScript project category (including its HTML5 project type) is entirely missing when go to *New Project*.

To fix this it looks I must install some plugin. However when I go to *Tools->Plugins->Available Plugins* no plugins are listed when click "Check for Newest".

This is most likely due to my iptables firewall blocking its connection. Now I would like to allow it via iptables. However when running `netstat` and `lsof` it seems to always use a different port. And in addition it uses tcp6 instead of tcp even though this shouldn't be a problem even with IPv4.

So how can I allow it in the iptables so that I can install the necessary to plugins to use this project type?

Comment: Why is that likely? Firewalls usually do not block outgoing connections.

Comment: I told my firewall to block outgoing connections by default.